# How can letters abcdef can be arranged so that a appears before b, c appears before d and e appears before f?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How can letters abcdef can be arranged so that a appears before b, c appears before d and e appears before f? If a general formula can be derived with this?

Note: a may be somewhere before b or c may be somewhere before d or e may be somewhere before f.....it need not to be immediate but will include cases where they are immediate before

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Conceptually this is the same as arrangements of *aaccee*. After arranging, modify the second of each repeat to the appropriate letter. Look up [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

Comment: Note that Mara Why has read your question as indicating that *a* appears **immediately** before *b*, not just **somewhere** before *b* (which is how I interpret it). Can you clarify?

Comment: a may be somewhere before b...it need not to be immediately before b

Comment: @ABHISHEKKUMAR Do you know the formula in currently accepted answer simplifies to $N!/2^n$ as concluded in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on only one pair at a time. In total $N!$ permutations, the sequences $AB$ and $BA$ occur equal number of times. Then $AB$ occurs $N!/2$ times.

If there are $n$ pairs of symbols relevant, we're looking for the following formula:

$$\frac{N!}{2^n}$$

For instance, here $N=6,n=3$. Answer is $$\frac{6!}{2^3}=90$$

Answer (score 1):

Place $a,b$ in a line with $a$ before $b$. There are now three places to put $c$ and $d$ (to the left of $a$, between $a$ and $b$ or to the right of $b$).

They can go into $1$ or $2$ of these places which can be chosen in
$3+\binom{3}{2}=6$ ways.

There are now five places for $e$ and $f$ which can be chosen in $5+\binom{5}{2}=15$ ways.

This gives us a total of $90$ possibilities.

I'm sure you can now see how to extend this to letters $g,h$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider row with 6 blocks...now two blocks to put (a,b) can be put using $\binom{6}{2}$....c and d can now be put in remaining 4 places using ${4 \choose 2}$. Total ways ${6 \choose 2}* {4 \choose 2}$ =90 ways

A general formula can be derived as ${n \choose 2}* {n-2 \choose 2}*{n-4 \choose 2}* {n-6 \choose 2}*{n-8 \choose 2}* {n-8 \choose 2}......$